# BigQuery external table creation failed with "autodetect" schema while reading a file from Google Drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, flysystem-google-drive

I am trying to create a BigQuery external table by reading a file from Google Drive - it works with inline scheme but failed with `autodetect` flag. 
**Document referenced:** 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive

**Schema File:**

```
$ bq mkdef --autodetect --source_format=CSV "https://drive.google.com/open?id=<file-id>" > schema.json
```

**schema.json:**

```
{
  "autodetect": true,
  "csvOptions": {
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "quote": "\""
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://drive.google.com/open?id=<file-id>"
  ]
}
```

**External Table:**

```
$ bq mk --external_table_definition=schema.json mydataset.mytable
BigQuery error in mk operation: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.
```

It works, with inline schema:

```
$ bq mk --external_table_definition=col1:INTEGER,col2:STRING@CSV=https://drive.google.com/open?id=<file-id> mydataset.mytable
Table 'myproject:mydataset.mytable' successfully created.
```

> **Note:** I have enabled Google Drive access by using `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually seems to be related to the authentication. For what it's worth, `gcloud` uses different OAuth token than `bq`.

I think the best course of action at this point is to:

1. look up `$HOME/.bigqueryrc`, there is `credential_file =`  line,
2. remove the `credential_file` referenced in the previous step (on Linux/macOS it's probably something like `.config/gcloud/...`),
3. run `gcloud auth --enable-gdrive-access --force`, the OAuth window should ask you for the permission to use GDrive too,
4. retry the creating external table definition.

If it still doesn't work, you can lookup what scopes are used with your token by previewing the file referenced in `credential_file`. It's a simple JSON file, and the scopes is just a list of URIs, there should be one with `drive` or `drive.read`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the culprit here is `"autodetect": true` [parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) , being specified in table definition file `--external_table_definition` when creating Bigquery [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table) from source data resided in Google Drive.

Actually `bq` command-line tool is a Python script which interacts with [Biqquery REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest), that means we trigger `tables.insert` API [method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) to create a permanent external table, supplying  appropriate [ExternalDataConfiguration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#externaldataconfiguration) in [Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#Table) json request body.

You can check it out performing the relevant API call to Bigquery API throughout [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/apis-explorer) consuming table definition parameters from `ExternalDataConfiguration`:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectid>/datasets/<datasetid>/tables?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"tableReference":{"datasetId":"datasetId","projectId":"projectId","tableId":"tableId"},"externalDataConfiguration":{"autodetect":true,"csvOptions":{"encoding":"UTF-8","quote":"\""},"sourceFormat":"CSV","sourceUris":["https://drive.google.com/open?id=<file-id>"]}}' \
  --compressed
```

I've received the same error in response message:

```
 "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accessDenied"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

For now, you can provide the schema inline (on the command line), or you can provide a JSON file containing the schema definition to get thing worked.

In order to keep this issue evidence more visible to developers, I would encourage you to file the bug report via **Public Issue** [tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com), thus we can keep track of any updates occurred or try to reach out Google [support](https://support.google.com/).